# Infrequent Firefox-only glitch: textarea shifted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I got this strange infrequent and firefox-only glitch on my web site.

[image: firefox glitch]

The textarea is shifted to the left, but the input above is still fine. The thing is, that this problem is infrequent and unpredictable - and it is always solved after refreshing the page.

The html code:

```
<form class='std_form' method='post' action='/kontakt-proceed/'>
<p><label for='kontakt_email'>Ihre E-Mail</label>
<input type='text' name='kontakt_email' id='kontakt_email'/></p>
<p><label for='kontakt_msg'>Ihre Nachricht</label>
<textarea name='kontakt_msg' id='kontakt_msg' rows='5' cols='4' class='noedit'>
</textarea>
</p>
<p><input type='submit' value='Abschicken'/></p>
</form>
```

And the css:

```
.footer_left{
width:35%;
float:left; 
color:white;
}
.footer_left label {display:block;margin-top:-3px;font-size:10px !important;}
.footer_left textarea {height:60px !important;width:240px !important;}
.footer_left input {width:240px !important;}
.footer_left p{margin-bottom:-13px;}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**  The problem seems to appear after a full refresh (CTRL+F5), but also infrequent.

Comment: Where's 'noedit'?  Any JS modifiying classes?

Comment: noedit is just for the :not - selector for tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

For your Textarea you must to set  this css:

```
#kontakt_msg{
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
}

.footer-left{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That'll work, if the problem was permanent. If I use the margin-left the textarea is always shifted to the right.

Comment: You can use position:absolute;left:30px; that you can see your textare in left

Comment: Yes, but that destroys the rest of the footer.

Comment: please set .footer_left{position:relative} after set position:absolute for kontakt_msg